# Do until inside a for loop stepping backwards?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, until-loop

I'm trying to write some code for a spreadsheet to calculate if items within a Bill of Materials (BoM) are a child of a purchased assembly or not. I'll try and explain in more detail.

Basically my spreadsheet has many columns, but only 2 are needed to calculate from. For simplicity I'll just say these are Columns A & B and the output from the VBA is put in Column C.

Column A contains the BoM level - This always starts at Level 0 and children of this level are level 1, and children of level 1 are level 2 and so on. Currently from all the BoMs I have created, level 10 has been 'deepest' it goes, but it isn't impossible that this could increase.

Column B contains the Assembly status - The only value I'm interested in this column is "P" for purchased.

Due to the various headings in my spreadsheet the data starts at Row 12 and as this is the Top Level I can always mark this as "TL" in Column C.

Now the bit I am struggling with. For each row from 13 onwards (this could easily extend to 100,000 rows and beyond!) I need to look at Column A (BoM level) and then look *upwards* to find the level **below** until I either find a level that is purchased ("P" in Column B) or reach BoM level 0.

Hopefully this table will help

| Column A | Column B | Column c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | IH | TL |
| 1 | IH | FALSE |
| 2 |  | FALSE |
| 2 |  | FALSE |
| 1 | P | FALSE |
| 2 | P | TRUE |
| 3 |  | TRUE |
| 3 |  | TRUE |

Whilst thinking of how to automate this issue, I thought I could use a For loop with a nested Select Case followed by a nested For loop (with Step -1).

The first For loop start at the top and look down to the last row, at each row it looks at the BoM Level and based on the this value a Select Case is used to run a For loop (Step -1) to start looking back up the rows.

The problem I can see is I would need to have a Case for each possible BoM level (the maximum total levels possible is 99)

Extract of code so far (only going to Case 3):

```
Sub Purch_Child_Formula()   'ADD CHILD OF PURCHASED ASSY FORMULA
Dim AssyStatus As Double
Dim ChildPurchStatus As Double
Dim CurrentBomLevel As Integer
Dim X As Long

Last_Row = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For ChildPurchStatus = 13 To Last_Row
    CurrentBomLevel = Cells(ChildPurchStatus, 1).Value
    
        Select Case CurrentBomLevel
        
        Case 1
            For X = ChildPurchStatus To 13 Step -1
            If Cells(X - 1, 1).Value = CurrentBomLevel Then
            Exit For
            ElseIf Cells(X - 1, 1).Value = (CurrentBomLevel - 1) And Cells(X - 1, 2).Value = "P" Then
                Cells(X, 3).Value = "TRUE"
            Else
                Cells(X, 3).Value = "FALSE"
            End If
            Next X
        Case 2
            For X = ChildPurchStatus To 13 Step -1
            If Cells(X - 1, 1).Value = CurrentBomLevel Then
            Exit For
            ElseIf Cells(X - 1, 1).Value = (CurrentBomLevel - 1) And Cells(X - 1, 2).Value = "P" Then
                Cells(X, 3).Value = "TRUE"
            ElseIf Cells(X - 1, 1).Value = (CurrentBomLevel - 2) And Cells(X - 1, 2).Value = "P" Then
                Cells(X, 3).Value = "TRUE"
            Else
                Cells(X, 3).Value = "FALSE"
            End If
            Next X
        Case 3
            For X = ChildPurchStatus To 13 Step -1
            If Cells(X - 1, 1).Value = CurrentBomLevel Then
            Exit For
            ElseIf Cells(X - 1, 1).Value = (CurrentBomLevel - 1) And Cells(X - 1, 2).Value = "P" Then
                Cells(X, 3).Value = "TRUE"
            ElseIf Cells(X - 1, 1).Value = (CurrentBomLevel - 2) And Cells(X - 1, 2).Value = "P" Then
                Cells(X, 3).Value = "TRUE"
            ElseIf Cells(X - 1, 1).Value = (CurrentBomLevel - 3) And Cells(X - 1, 2).Value = "P" Then
                Cells(X, 3).Value = "TRUE"
            Else
                Cells(X, 3).Value = "FALSE"
            End If
            Next X
        Case 4
            
        Case 5
            
        Case 6
            
        Case 7
            
        Case 8
            
        Case 9
            
        Case 10
        
        End Select
            
Next ChildPurchStatus
    
End Sub
```

This starts to work, but does go wrong before reaching a BoM Level of 4.

So now I'm thinking that perhaps I should use an initial for loop to down the rows, followed but another for loop looking back up the data, but this for loop should continue until it finds the criteria "P" in Column 2 - and we've arrived at an Until loop. Is this possible? (It may be evident that coding is not part of my normal job!)

Sorry for the very wordy post, but my scenario seems to unique as some searching online hasn't helped so far.

Hopefully there is enough information in this post. I will add any other details requested.

Comment: What the logic to populate TRUE or FALSE in col C?

Comment: If there's any P between current row and BoM level 0? Because then you can keep a boolean (P was found) which resets with every BoM and then check if it's true or not. But then go from 13 to last row. You could also reset if Ax is smaller than Ax-1 for example if that's necessary since you mention *"the level below"*

Comment: @taller Apologies - I knew I would miss something. TRUE needs to be entered in col C if any BoM Level above has a "P" in col B. Confusingly the BoM Level above is the (BoM Level - 1).
If there are no levels above then FALSE should be entered in col C. In my table above, the items at the bottom that are Level 3 in col A are TRUE because their level above them (level 2) has a "P" in col B. Equally that level 2 is also TRUE is col C because the level above is also purchased ("P" is col B). However the levels above this are FALSE because no level above contains a "P" in col C

Comment: @Notus_Panda Your suggestion of Boolean look promising. However the "P" can only be at levels that are above (or more accurately less than) the current BoM Level. My example doesn't show it, but there are instances where a "P" could be found above the current row but the BoM level will be equal to or greater than the current row's BoM level.

Comment: To try and give a better example. If I'm evaluating a row within the data where the Level in col A was "4". I would need to look back up the cells in col A to find the next "3" and see if col B contained a "P", if not I would need to look for the next "2", if this didn't contain a "P" in col B, I would need to look for the next "1". and if "0" didn't contain a "P" in col B I could input FALSE into col C.

Comment: I don't see why you need VBA for this. As far as I can tell, you are only concerned with the existence of 'P' in lines above the current row where a level exists that is less than the current level. You should be able to just `FILTER` the rows above the current row then test for an inequality of MIN(filtered row levels) < current level for TRUE.

Comment: @Tragamor. The reason for using VBA is at present the col C data is calculated using a formula. However when pasting the formula to the full range (in this case 96,263 rows) excel runs out of resources and crashes (3GB seems to be the most RAM it can use -even though I have 48GB). Also VBA is already used in the spreadsheet to validate other data properties.

My limited understanding is the resource usage of Excel would reduce if the calculation was done once with VBA rather than using a very long formula. Currently to validate the 96,000 dataset is taking ~5 hours, and needs 64bit Excel.

Answer (score 2):

You could just do this with a formula.

```
=COUNTIFS(RC3:OFFSET(RC1,MAX(FILTER(ROW(R1C1:RC1),R1C1:RC1=0))-ROW(RC),2),"=P")>0
```

[image: spreadsheet]

In A1 mode, my cell `D1` has this:

```
=COUNTIFS($C1:OFFSET($A1,MAX(FILTER(ROW($A$1:$A1),$A$1:$A1=0))-ROW(D1),2),"=P")>0
```

Comment: Almost right, in his example, the 1 with a P doesn't have TRUE. OP also mentions it as such: *However the "P" can only be at levels that are above (or more accurately less than) the current BoM Level*

Answer (score 1):

*The Boolean solution*

As discussed before, I use a boolean and to keep track of which BoM lvl is the lowest, I have one extra variable for that as well:

```
Sub Purch_Child_Formula()   'ADD CHILD OF PURCHASED ASSY FORMULA
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long, bomLvl As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pCheck As Boolean
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    If lRow < 13 Then
        MsgBox "Not enough rows to check"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim arr, arrPr
    arr = ws.Range("A13:B" & lRow).Value 'from your example
    ReDim arrPr(1 To UBound(arr, 1), 1 To 1)
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        If arr(i, 1) = 0 Then 'resetting
            pCheck = False
            bomLvl = 0
        End If
        If arr(i, 2) = "P" Then
            If Not pCheck Then
                pCheck = True
                bomLvl = arr(i, 1)
            End If
            If bomLvl > arr(i, 1) Then bomLvl = arr(i, 1)
        End If
        arrPr(i, 1) = pCheck And bomLvl < arr(i, 1)
        'there is a P and its BoM is lower than current one ... or not
    Next i
    
    ws.Range("C13:C" & lRow).Value = arrPr 'print everything at once
End Sub
```

Let me know if the following result is wrong:

- 0 resets everything
- lvl 3 has P -> lvl 4 and above are True
- lvl 2 has P so now lvl 3 and above are True
  [image]

Comment: Thank you for this. Interestingly a colleague (who I was unaware dabbled with VBA) suggested using a Boolean and it worked a treat. Not only will it run without hitting a resource limit on 32-bit Excel but the time to process the ~96000 line dataset reduced from around 5 hours to 6 minute and 18 seconds. I'm chuffed with that! I will add the code tomorrow for anyone interested as it may help others with a similar problem.

Comment: My code ran in a second for 400k+ lines so I'm interested to see what's causing the time-increase on your end. My guess would be using cells().Value (interaction with Excel) rather than an array (in memory)

Comment: I changed my code to use an array and it is massively quicker. It now takes 3 seconds to run through the full dataset. Although I have run into a separate issue, but I'll ask a new question about that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

- Using `Dictionary` object to store the status of upper BoM.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim Sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim arrRes, rngRes As Range
    Dim objDic As Object, sKey As Long
    Set Sht1 = Sheets("Sheet1") ' Modify as needed
    Set rngRes = Sht1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion ' Modify as needed
    arrRes = rngRes.Value
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' Loop through data
    For i = LBound(arrRes) To UBound(arrRes)
        sKey = CLng(arrRes(i, 1))
        If Not objDic.exists(sKey) Or UCase(arrRes(i, 2)) = "P" Then
            objDic(sKey) = UCase(arrRes(i, 2))
        End If
        If sKey > 0 Then
            arrRes(i, 3) = False
            ' Loop through up BoM
            For j = sKey - 1 To 0 Step -1
                If objDic(j) = "P" Then
                    arrRes(i, 3) = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next i
    ' Update data on sheet
    rngRes.Value = arrRes
End Sub
```